# radial-gradient not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, radial-gradients

This does not work in Firefox 22:

```
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(48% -42%, 138px 138px, green 0%, lightblue 100%);
```

But it works in Chrome:

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(48% -42%, 138px 138px, green 0%, lightblue 100%);
```

It's the second argument Firefox has a problem with. If changed to

```
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #008000 0%, #add8e6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
```

it works in FF, but that was not really the effect I'm after!

[jsbin with example](http://jsbin.com/iwoqud/3/)

Comment: have you tried it without the `-moz-` prefix -- you shouldn't need to use a prefix for gradients in Firefox any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's Mozilla bug. It doesn't support defined size radial gradient.

[**SEE**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627885)