# CSS radial gradient not working in Mozilla

Tags: css, cross-browser, radial-gradients

I have the following CSS code:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#7b7878), to(@white));
background: -moz-radial-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#7b7878), to(@white));
background: radial-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#7b7878), to(@white));
```

Which is responsible for the following styling:

[image]

It works in Chrome, but this is not working in Firefox and IE. What am I missing here??

Comment: possible duplicate of [radial-gradient not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059878/radial-gradient-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059878/radial-gradient-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code, this will work on IE 10,google chrom 26.0,fire fox 16.0 ,opera 12.1 and safari 6.1:

```
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#7B7878 1%, #BBBBBB 30%, #CCCCCC 40%, #FFF 70%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(#7B7878 1%, #BBBBBB 30%, #CCCCCC 40%, #FFF 70%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(#7B7878 1%, #BBBBBB 30%, #CCCCCC 40%, #FFF 70%);
  background: radial-gradient(#7B7878 1%, #BBBBBB 30%, #CCCCCC 40%, #FFF 70%);
```

And also give the same result as you want.